# How to check existence of key in array of Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an `NSArray` Which contains a `NSDictionarry` Like this:

```
 NSArray *myArray = {  

                     "city" = "somecity";
                      Country = "someCountry";
                    }
```

How can I check whether the key `city` exists or not.

If the key `city` is not present the i am getting `<null>` . I don't know how to compare this `<null>` .

```
  NSArray *fetch = [myArray valueForKey:@"city"];
```

This gives me 1 object that is `<null>` if key `city` not present.

Comment: Why are you searching on "name" if you want to see if "city" is there?

Comment: its just for example

Comment: I might be missing something but I really don't understand this code. Seems to be a `@{}` dictionary but without the `@` and on a `NSArray`? How this works?

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
NSArray *myArray = {  
                     "city" = "somecity";
                      Country = "someCountry";
                    }
```

in not an array it is dictionary an array will be something like this

```
NSArray *myArray = @[@{@"City" : @"Indore",@"Country" : @"India"}];
```

Now if you want to check whether a key with city exist in the dictionary or not you can check that like this

```
if([[myArray objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"City"]){
    NSLog(@"Available");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Not Available");
}
```